# How many actions can be added to an iOS push notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

What is the maximum number of actions that can be associated with a push notification and still show up on the lock screen?  For example, in this picture, there are two actions.  Is it possible to put more than that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

NO

**banner**、**lock screen**、**notification center** up to 2 actions

**notification alert** up to 4 actions

See:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/NotificationCenter.html